# different templates based on $item number

Tags: php7

```
foreach ($this->intro_items as $key => &$item) {
    $this->item = &$item;
    echo $this->loadTemplate('item');
}
```

I would like to be able to change the template used for specific items in the `foreach` statement. The first 2 `$item`s should use template A, then switch to template B for `$item`s 3,4.  Then back to template A.

Comment: thinking this is going to work:

foreach ($this->intro_items as $key => &$item) : 
    $this->item = &$item;
    if (($key/2)%2) {
         echo $this->loadTemplate('item');
    } else {
         echo $this->loadTemplate('other item');
    }
 endforeach;

Comment: Please provide more details in your questions. What framework or cms (+ version number) you use for example and please consider to wrap code with the given preformat function for code (the curly brackets icon in the editor).

Comment: @ChrisArmstrong If your commented solution works, you should post it as an answer.  If it doesn't work, please add it to your question via Edit and explain that that is your best coding attempt, then try to clarify what is left to fix AND respond to Dennis' request for additional details.  Please always endeavor to progress your question(s) toward an accepted answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

this ended up working for me.

```
foreach ($this->intro_items as $key => &$item) : 
 $this->item = &$item;
  if (($key/2)%2) {
   echo $this->loadTemplate('item');
  } else {
   echo $this->loadTemplate('item2');
  }
endforeach;
```